# Inaccurate confusion matrix for a model with 98% test accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, confusion-matrix

I trained a model for binary classification and received 98% of test accuracy and 99% of training accuracy.

Today I wanted to calculate the confusion matrix and used below code to calculate them.

```
model = load_model("model.h5")

testGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=5,
                                width_shift_range=0.2,
                                height_shift_range=0.2,
                                horizontal_flip=False,
                                fill_mode='nearest'
                                )   

testData = testGenerator.flow_from_directory(
                                'Location', 
                                target_size=(74,448),                                                 
                                batch_size=15,
                                class_mode='binary',
                                shuffle=False
                                )

proba = model.predict_generator(testData,steps=3000//15)
y_true = np.array([0] * 1482 + [1] * 1482 )
y_pred = proba > 0.5
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
```

And I received this confusion matrix :

[image: Confusion Matrix]

As sklearn says :

[image]

Which says here false negative and false positive are so high. How is that even possible since I had 98% of testing accuracy? Also I've used that model few times to generate predictions (using model.predict() fuction) and manually checked them. But each time it gave me correct classifications.

Any Ideas how to get accurate results?

Comment: Is your true data really distributed like your y_true variable?

Comment: @CupinaCoffee I've set `shuffle=false` to make it so.

Comment: Okay. Check to comment from soumendra in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3477

Comment: @CupinaCoffee Thanks. I went through that post before but he has used train_generator.class_indices which I don't have since I've already trained the model.

Comment: Sounds like your initial model might have been overfit during the training.  Can you describe your process training the model?

Comment: @vealkind I did use `Earlystopping` method to ensure overfitting will not happen. also my dataset for training, validation and testing never had same data. Also dropout layers were used.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the end. The message "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" means you cannot use `numpy.ndarray` as a dictionary key, because it's not an immutable object. Convert it to `tuple` or something else to make immutable first.

About your confusion matrix, I bet the generator loads files from the folder in an unpredictable order, still, you have `y_true` set to 1482 `zeros` and 1482 `ones` -- which may or may not match the order of the files produces by the generator. Hence the funny results you get.

Comment: I recently fixed that error. But still predictions come from predict_generator() are not accurate as predict() outcomes.  Also, I've set shuffle=false. Then how would it consider them unpredictable way?

Comment: @Sam94 well, don't use `predict_generator()`, then?

Comment: To generate confusion matrix and perform statistical analysis it's better to have large number of samples right? (At least 500). But I only have images like 100. So I need to augment them and predict. What other possible solutions available for me then?

Comment: @Sam94 I'm not against generators, it's just your labels don't fit the dataset. Calculate the confusion matrix on the data you have. If you get significantly better results, fix the way you generate the data and ground truth.

Comment: I used images I have without generating images and got accurate results.I mean with predict() function.Not with predict_generator(). So I need to correct this problem. That's why I seek some help

Comment: @Sam94 don't use generator in your code, create some images separately, save to disk, make sure the `y_true` fits the data.